# window.addEventListener doesn't throw an error or go into the function

Tags: javascript, service-worker, addeventlistener

We are getting the following error in our code and I cannot figure out what the error is. It doesn't the function which contains the service worker registration ('load' event listener) or to the function in "error" event handler.
Is there any other debugging mechanism I can see why my service worker is not getting registered?

By the way, same code works fine in Chrome 104 *(104.0.5112.102)*, but not in 105,106 107, or in Edge. Is there an upcoming change?

```
            window.addEventListener("load", function () {
              navigator.serviceWorker
                .register("mservice-service-worker.js")
                .then(function (registration) {
                  console.log("ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ",registration.scope);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                  console.log("ServiceWorker registration failed: ", err);
                });
            });
            window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
              console.log("Got an uncaught error: ", event.error)
            })
```

Our code is written in AngularJS 1.8

Comment: How do you know that the listener didn't run? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: You can check which serviceWorker is registered in dev tools.

Comment: Do you already have the service working running, service workers don't register every time you render the page, it does a hash check.  You can see if you have a service worker in the Application tab of chrome, you can then manually delete to re-run the registration etc.

Comment: Yes I tried debugging. Not working in local server but debugged in localhost. No registered service worker in Application tab

Comment: `Not working in local server but debugged in localhost.`  What do you mean here, are you saying localhost is a OK, if so, remember service workers require a secure context, either `localhost`, or `https://` protocol.  Does the console say anything?.

Comment: Sorry @Keith ignore that. It doesn;t work in both production or in localhost.  Production server has https://. And the same code works with Chrome 104. Console says nothing. Thats why I tried adding the EventListener for "error"

Comment: 105, 106, 107, current version is 104, so I'm assuming your running some Beta versions,.  It might be best reporting this to https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/

Comment: @Keith thought of doing that but other pages with service workers do get registered. So we were in two minds.

Comment: To rule out the "load" event having been already fired, what do you get if you log `document.readyState` immediately before the `window.addEventListener` call?

Comment: @traktor interesting, Chrome 104 -Interactive , Chrome 105 - complete

Comment: So the behavior of the code is no longer a mystery although whether it's a bug or remains to be seen. Perhaps you should report it with a minimal reproducible example - after checking it still works in Firefox of course ;) Good luck with solving it or finding a work-around.

Comment: @traktor thanks mate. Yes we will do that. Trying to figure out where is the best place to put our code to resolve the issue if that's the way it will be have in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've encountered the same issue, but in React. I've tried to register the service worker in a component and the "load" event did not triggered.

I've reported the bug on the chromium website and it seems like the issue started with Chormium version 104.0.5084.0.

The issue is present in all Chromium based browsers like Brave and Edge.

You can follow the progress here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1372748

Answer (score 0):

From comment discussion the code is not working because the load event has been and gone and the added event listener is never executed.

As a work-around you could check before adding the listener and call it if already loaded:

```
const startWorker = function () {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register("mservice-service-worker.js")
    .then(function (registration) {
      console.log("ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ",registration.scope);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log("ServiceWorker registration failed: ", err);
    });
};

if( document.readyState != "complete") {
  window.addEventListener("load", startWorker);
}
else {
  startWorker();
}
```

This doesn't solve whether the new behavior is a bug or not.  It is conceivable that a race condition existed in version 104 and earlier that has only come to light because of improvements introduced in 105. It is also conceivable that 105 introduced a bug. Analysis of modular script loading and possibly deferred script usage may shed some light on the exact nature of the problem.